# ASP.NET MVC 5 drops trailing period on redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm dealing with string IDs in a legacy system.  I added `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"` and `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in the web.config, which fixes 404s when browsing directly to a route ending in a period (i.e. `/view/company abc inc.`).

`RedirectToResult` is dropping the trailing period of an entity ID.  Why is this?  How can I redirect to a route which ends in a period?

[image: Notice the period being lost after redirect]

Update: I noticed that the Location header in the redirect is wrong, but the RedirectResult that generates it is correct:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://localhost:3000/view/apple%20inc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being in the `web.config`.  Changing `UseFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl` from `true` to `false` fixed it.